# Login with twitter is not sending Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-login

I am trying to implement twitter login in ASP.Net with C#. I want to fetch the registered email address of the twitter user but my code is giving error:

> An error occurred while parsing the Twitter response

This might be because ***dataTable.Rows[0]["email"].ToString()*** is invalid here. However, other details are being fetched perfectly. Following is my code:

```
empty = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json";
str = twitterAuth.OAuthWebRequest(TwitterAuth.Method.GET, empty, string.Format("screen_name={0}", screenName));
dataTable = JsonStringToDataTable(str);
objTwitterBO.TwitterUserEmailId = dataTable.Rows[0]["email"].ToString();
objTwitterBO.TwitterUserID = dataTable.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString();
objTwitterBO.TwitterUserPhotoUrl = dataTable.Rows[0]["profile_image_url"].ToString();
objTwitterBO.TwitterUserName = dataTable.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
objTwitterBO.TwitterUserScreenName = dataTable.Rows[0]["screen_name"].ToString();
```

Code of **OAuthWebRequest** is as under:

```
string empty = string.Empty;
      string str = string.Empty;
        string empty1 = string.Empty;
        if ((method == TwitterAuth.Method.POST || method == TwitterAuth.Method.DELETE ? true : method == TwitterAuth.Method.GET))
        {
            if (postData.Length > 0)
            {
                NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(postData);
                postData = string.Empty;
                string[] allKeys = nameValueCollection.AllKeys;
                for (int i = 0; i < (int)allKeys.Length; i++)
                {
                    string str1 = allKeys[i];
                    if (postData.Length > 0)
                    {
                        postData = string.Concat(postData, "&");
                    }
                    nameValueCollection[str1] = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(nameValueCollection[str1]);
                    nameValueCollection[str1] = TwitterBase.UrlEncode(nameValueCollection[str1]);
                    postData = string.Concat(postData, str1, "=", nameValueCollection[str1]);
                }
                if (url.IndexOf("?") <= 0)
                {
                    url = string.Concat(url, "?");
                }
                else
                {
                    url = string.Concat(url, "&");
                }
                url = string.Concat(url, postData);
                string postDataplus = "&include_email=true";
                url = string.Concat(url, postDataplus);

            }
        }
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        string str2 = this.GenerateNonce();
        string str3 = this.GenerateTimeStamp();
        string str4 = base.GenerateSignature(uri, this.ConsumerKey, this.ConsumerSecret, this.Token, this.TokenSecret, this.CallBackUrl, this.OAuthVerifier, method.ToString(), str3, str2, out empty, out str);
        str = string.Concat(str, "&oauth_signature=", TwitterBase.UrlEncode(str4));
        if ((method == TwitterAuth.Method.POST ? true : method == TwitterAuth.Method.DELETE))
        {
            postData = str;
            str = string.Empty;
        }
        if (str.Length > 0)
        {
            empty = string.Concat(empty, "?");
        }
        empty1 = this.WebRequest(method, string.Concat(empty, str), postData);
        return empty1;
```

Please tell me how to fetch the email address from twitter with this code.

Comment: `My code is giving error` what error?

Comment: It fails to parse because it didnot find "email" in the response

Comment: That means you need to figure out why Twitter is not returning email id. You need to check if the screenName you are passing have allowed emailId to be shared to the Twitter API clients.

Comment: In my twitter app, getting Email id is allowed but I am not able to fetch it here with my code.

Comment: Are you sending appropriate token along with the request? Does that token have appropriate grant type?

Comment: As I mentioned in the description itself, I am getting other details. In absence of authorization or token, I couldnot fetch other details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153229/discussion-between-shobhit-gupta-and-chetan-ranpariya).

Answer (score 2):

The email address is not available on the users/show endpoint. You need to use the [validate_credentials](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials) endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Andy Piper ... Can you please add up the code in my code that would solve my problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with ASP.NET to help here.